# How to join two SKSpriteNodes using SKPhysicsJointFixed

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

When I attempt to join two SKSpriteNodes with SKPhysicsJointFixed, they separate as if not connected at all. Nothing I do seems to work. Here's my code...

```
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(4, 64);

SKSpriteNode *node1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:size];
node1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size];
node1.position = position;

SKSpriteNode *node2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:size];
node2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size];
node2.position = position;

[scene addChild:node1];
[scene addChild:node2];

SKPhysicsJointFixed *joint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:node1.physicsBody
                                                            bodyB:node2.physicsBody
                                                          anchor:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[scene.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's working... but try other position for node2, let's say...  CGPoint position2 = CGPointMake(100, 120); ... node2.position = position2;

Comment: what is not working? please, check my code... but your code it's also ok, just change the node's color :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my working code....

```
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(100, 350);
CGPoint position2 = CGPointMake(100, 420);
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(4, 164);

SKSpriteNode *node1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:size];
node1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size];
node1.position = position;

SKSpriteNode *node2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:size];
node2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size];
node2.position = position2;

[scene addChild:node1];
[scene addChild:node2];

SKPhysicsJointFixed *joint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:node1.physicsBody
                                                                   bodyB:node2.physicsBody
                                                                  anchor:CGPointMake(node1.position.x, node1.position.y-30)];

[scene.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
```